# How to find index of a specific element in a JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

So using [this JSON data](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v1.2/stats/by-summoner/26026414/summary?api_key=b05c2251-f659-4d24-8b5f-6b25a482b42a) I'm trying to find the location of the element that contains value "RankedSolo5x5" previously I thought I could just do this:

```
$("#rankedStats").append("Ranked wins: " + obj.playerStatSummaries[5].wins + "</br>" +
                                     "Ranked losses:" + obj.playerStatSummaries[5].losses + "</br>" +
                                     "w/l ratio: " + obj.playerStatSummaries[5].wins/obj.playerStatSummaries[5].losses + "</br>" +
                                     "Total Ranked Kills: " + obj.playerStatSummaries[5].aggregatedStats.totalChampionKills);
```

however unfortunately for me soon enough I found out that for different players the location of "RankedSolo5x5" will be different for some players, so it could be `obj.playerStatSummaries[6].losses` or `obj.playerStatSummaries[7].losses`, therefore I need to find the element that contains "RankedSolo5x5" so I tried to put all of the values in an array and use `$.inArray("RankedSolo5x5", entry)`, like so:

```
 $.getJSON("https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + region + "/v1.2/stats/by-summoner/" + sID + "/summary?api_key=b05c2251-f659-4d24-8b5f-6b25a482b42a", function(stats){
            obj = stats;
            var entry = [];
            $.each(obj.playerStatSummaries, function(key, value){
                entry.push(JSON.stringify(key) + ', ' + JSON.stringify(value));
                $("#rankedStats").append($.inArray("RankedSolo5x5", entry));
            });
```

however it just returns -1 and now I'm kind of stuck and out of ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following,

```
$.each(obj.playerStatSummaries, function(index, el){
      if(el.playerStatSummaryType==='RankedSolo5x5'){
        console.log(index);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't need jQuery for the simplest of tasks (and you'll come out a better person if you know some basic javascript):

```
var found = false;
for  (var i = 0; i < obj.playerStatSummaries.length; ++i) {
  var summary = obj.playerStatSummaries[i];
  if  (summary.losses == 'RankedSolo5x5') {
    found = summary;
    break;
  }
}

if (found) {
  // ... do something with it.
}
```